# Read NFC from createMime value data on an android

Tags: java, android, nfc

I write tag to NFC successful creating with CreateMime.How we can read and getdata string from NFC createmime value to show textview android layout? Please help any one...

```
    @Override
   protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    // Tag writing mode
    if (mWriteMode && NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Tag detectedTag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);

        NdefRecord name = NdefRecord.createMime( ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvname)).getText().toString(), ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString().getBytes());
        NdefRecord phone = NdefRecord.createMime( ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvphone)).getText().toString(), ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.phone)).getText().toString().getBytes());
        NdefMessage message = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] { name,phone });
        if (writeTag(message, detectedTag)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Success: Wrote placeid to nfc tag", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        } 
    }
}
```

Writes an NdefMessage to a NFC tag

```
   public boolean writeTag(NdefMessage message, Tag tag) {
    int size = message.toByteArray().length;
    try {
        Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
        if (ndef != null) {
            ndef.connect();
            if (!ndef.isWritable()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Error: tag not writable",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
            if (ndef.getMaxSize() < size) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Error: tag too small",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
            ndef.writeNdefMessage(message);
            return true;
        } else {
            NdefFormatable format = NdefFormatable.get(tag);
            if (format != null) {
                try {
                    format.connect();
                    format.format(message);
                    return true;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your onCreate, write the following:

```
Intent intent=getIntent();
```

And then invoke the read method.

```
private void read(Intent intent)
{
    try{
        Parcelable msgs[] = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);    
        NdefMessage msg = (NdefMessage) msgs[0];
        NdefRecord nameRecord = msg.getRecords()[0];
        NdefRecord phnoRecord = msg.getRecords()[1];
        String name,phno;
        byte[] namepayload = nameRecord.getPayload();
        byte[] phnopayload = phnoRecord.getPayload();

        String textEncoding = ((namePayload[0] & 0200) == 0) ? "UTF-8" : "UTF-16";
        int languageCodeLength = namePayload[0] & 0077;
        name = new String(namepayload,  languageCodeLength + 1, namepayload.length - languageCodeLength - 1, textEncoding);
        phno = new String(phnoPayload, languageCodeLength + 1, phnopayload.length - languageCodeLength - 1, textEncoding);
        t1.setText(name);
        t2.setText(phno);
    }
    catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){}
}
```